# Is it possible to build own customized laptop?

Tags: laptop, computer-building, build, components, barebone

I was thinking to build my own customized laptop, but as I am from Software Engineering background, I need guidance here. Firstly, I want to ask that is building own laptop even possible? If yes, are the barebone casings (shell) of laptops (with hinges, keyboard, mousepad) available in the market, on which I can fit the motherboard (and other components) OR vice versa (if I choose the motherboard, then can I find the relevant barebone casing for it)?

Comment: Anything is possible if you have the money.

Comment: So you mean to say that there is not an economic way to build? Not even closer (slight higher) to what all the known brands are selling in market?

Comment: Its possible I suppose, depending on your skills, tools and time available to dedicate to the project. Have you ever disassembled a laptop to see how complicated and intricate they are?

Comment: Yeah, I have seen internals of few laptops (totally naked). I know there is very little space in there to accommodate many things. That's what my question was intended, can we get required (compatible) motherboard and laptop body case (cabinet) in the market which can fit in together?